# How is CSRF token verified?

Tags: csrf

I would like to know how the CSRF tokens are verified on form submit?

Please tell me  whether the following is correct:

- Server issues a random string which is set as the session cookie, and a value for the hidden field in the form.
- On the form submit, the server checks the session cookie with the hidden field value for equality, if values are not equal it won't process the request.

Comment: nope, because than the attack can easily forge them.  its more of a rand() that gets assigned to a hidden value . that is matched against the rand() stored with the session.(so on the server)

Comment: @LvB this comment smells like an answer.

Comment: @LvB As long as the string is random, I think this is secure. An attacker can't read the data to learn the token value and they can't alter the cookie value to make it match what they set in the fiekd

Comment: Everything you need to know: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet The double submit cookie pattern (that you describe) is also there...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is one possible approach to defending against CSRF. It's called the [double submit cookie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie) pattern.

The synchronizer token pattern - the second token isn't stored in a cookie but server-side in the session - is a bit more common in practice though.